# How do I include a stored procedures schema name in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I would like to select all of the stored procedures in my database preceded by their schema name.

For example I would like my output columns to show `dbo.stored_procedure` instead of just `stored_procedure`.

So what I'm looking for is something like

```
select SCHEMA_NAME + '.' + name
from sys.procedures
order by name
```

But this won't work because of `schema_name` being an invalid column name

Comment: Is there a column called `SCHEMA_NAME` in table `sys.procedures`?  You can't just make up random column name, and expect SQL Server to magically display the value you expect.

Comment: I suspect the OP is confusing the `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects, @Eric , which *does* have a column called `SCHEMA_NAME`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schema name is in a different object if you're using the `sys` objects:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(p.name)
FROM sys.procedures p
     JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
ORDER BY p.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`sys.procedures` has a field `schema_id` which is a foreignkey to `sys.schemas`. So you simply need to join to it

```
select s.name + '.' + p.name
from sys.procedures p
inner join sys.schemas s
    on p.schema_id = s.schema_id
order by p.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INFORMATION_SHEMA.ROUTINES`:

```
select ROUTINE_SCHEMA + '.' + ROUTINE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```

You can use either `SPECIFIC_` or `ROUTINE_`.  However, the `SPECIFIC_` are for overloaded procedures (i.e. two procedures with the same name but that take different arguments).  SQL Server doesn't support this.  If it did, though, you would want the generic name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`SCHEMA_NAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/schema-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function to get the schema name as

```
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_Name(schema_id)), N'.', QUOTENAME(Name)) Result
FROM Sys.Procedures
ORDER BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + '.' + SPECIFIC_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```